# 3D Vector defined by 2 angles

Tags: math, vector, 3d

So basically I'm looking for a way to calculate the x, y and z component of a vector using 2 angles as shown:
[image]
Where alpha is the 2D angle and beta is the y angle.
What I've been using uptill now for 2D vectors was:

```
x = Math.sin(alpha);
z = Math.cos(alpha);
```

After searching on stackexchange math I've found this forumula doesn't really work correctly:

```
 x = Math.sin(alpha)*Math.cos(beta);
 z = Math.sin(alpha)*Math.sin(beta);
 y = Math.cos(beta);
```

Note: when approaching 90 degrees with the beta angle the x and z components should approach zero.
All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The proper formulas would be

```
x = Math.cos(alpha) * Math.cos(beta);
z = Math.sin(alpha) * Math.cos(beta);
y = Math.sin(beta);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works and makes a lot more sense. (i had to switch the x and z but that's just how my enviroment is set)

Comment: @MoffKalast Two angles on perpendicular planes are sufficient to define a vector in 3D space. You could calculate the angle of the projection on the third plane (in this example, XY) using the first two angles.

Comment: Any idea on how to compute it, if the used x,y,z directions were relative to a plane of a model, and not relative to the coordinate-system the model sits within?

Comment: I took a stab at doing this in 4D, I came up with:
a = Math.cos(gamma);
x = Math.cos(alpha)*Math.cos(beta)*a;
z = Math.sin(alpha)*Math.cos(beta)*a;
y = Math.sin(beta)*a;
w = Math.sin(gamma);
How close was I?

Comment: Given alpha and beta, what is the angle between red and green lines.

Answer (score -1):

That formula just come from the transformation of [Spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) (r, theta, phi) -> (x, y, z) to Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: The angle beta shown by OP is not the same as the polar angle in spherical coordinates