# 3D Vector defined by 2 angles around a normal

Tags: vector, linear-algebra, polar-coordinates

I'm having trouble with a part of a school project of mine.

I need to find the vector `v` defined by the angles alpha and beta, but relative to a normal `n` instead of relative to the z axis.

I saw this question and answer, but it's only relative to the z axis, and I'm having trouble understanding how I can find `v` around a normal instead: [3D Vector defined by 2 angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011741/3d-vector-defined-by-2-angles)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need two vectors, if you give me the normal vector and an angle between the point and that vector, that can be satisfied by a family of points that lie in a circle.

Then you need a second vector to determine which point is the correct one.

Comment: Can you clarify what point you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry, vector instead of point, they are two different interpretation of the coordinates, and I got confused.